# Where to put calculation executed regularly that updates actor's internal state?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am learning Scala and Akka.

In the problem I am trying to solve I want an actor to be reading a real-time data stream and perform a certain calculation that would update its state.

Every 3 seconds I am sending a request through a Scheduler for the actor to return to its state.

While I have pretty much everything implemented, with my actor having a broadcaster and receiver and the function to update the state right. I am not entirely sure how to do it, I could potentially put the calculations always running in a separate thread inside the actor but I would like to now if there is a more elegant way to make this in scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to divide the work between two actors. The parent actor would manage child worker actor and would track the state. It sends a message to the child worker actor to trigger data processing.

The child worker actor processes the data stream - don't forget to wrap the processing into a `Future` so that it doesn't block the actor from processing messages. It also periodically sends messages to the master with current state. So the child worker is stateless, it sends notifications when its state changes.

If you want to know the current state of the work overall, you ask the master. In principle, you can merge this into one actor which sends the status message to itself. I wouldn't update the state directly to avoid concurrency issues. The reason is that the data processing work running in the `Future` can possible run on a different thread than message processing.